# Unable to start 'network' in recovery mode

Tags: boot, networking, 18.04

After upgrade to 18.04, my system does not work anymore, staying on `Started gnome display manager.`  I tried to start in console mode to recover the situation.  Unfortunately, this means accessing the console in root mode, with r/w access on the disk.
I tried to first use fsck then root.  It works, but without network.
I then tried the option 'network' but then the system hangs on

```
Created slice system-configure\x2dprinter.slice
```

How to get out of this mess?

Comment: Can you reach the grub menu?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to boot to `runlevel3` to access network without the GUI from the grub menu. Follow these steps:

1. Boot to the grub menu
2. Make sure your selection is the first entry, then press the <kbd>e</kbd> key to access the kernel command line.
3. Use your cursor to go down to where you will see the word `linux`, at that point press the <kbd>end</kbd> key. This will take you to the end of that line.
4. Using the <kbd>backspace</kbd> key delete the entry `$vt_handoff`, then add this line there:

   ```
   systemd.unit=runlevel3.target
   ```
5. Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> to boot.

You should be in the runlevel 3 which gives you access to network on your system.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this does not work.  I open a new question with more detail.

Comment: What did not work which part?

Comment: I could make the modifications you suggested.  Only, booting afterwards did not show any screen (be it terminal or GUI).  The reason I needed internet access was to allow various update/upgrade/reconfiguration.  Unfortunately, from the recovery menu, the 'root' option does not allow any modification (disks are mounted read/only) unless I ran an 'fsck' first.  At that point, I could access the disks in read/write but without network.  The option 'Internet' was supposed to start the network before opening a 'root' session.  This one was never reached.  Thank you for your explanation, anyway.

Comment: Please restart your system and try these steps again!

Comment: Impossible.  In the meantime, I proceeded to a fresh installation, to get a functional system as soon as possible.

Comment: This somewhat worked for me. Not quite as expected, but I do have network, which is an improvement.